# Can we bootstrap Crashlytics on a background thread on iOS?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

We are trying to reduce the cold start latency in our iOS application and we noticed that Crashlytics can take between 50 and 150ms (on low end devices) to do it's setup through their API:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

This is instructed to run as early as possible in the app lifecycle.

Has anyone found documentation or tried running this bit of code in a background queue with success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you init on the background thread, you run the risk of missing crashes on app launch, so technically you can, but there are tradeoffs that are made. In general, in my testing, I see an init of 30-60ms.

Comment: If you go this route, you may want to dispatch_wait for it to complete at the end of application:didFinishLaunching: just so you don't miss crashes in arbitrary bits of code that execute after app initialization as well.  But, probably less of a win if you do that too.

Comment: Yea not a bad idea - I think we might try using our own rudimentary crash reporter for the brief time that Crashlytics is not bootstrapped.

Comment: As a heads up, that will be risky as well as iOS supports only one running uncaught exception handler.

Comment: @MikeBonnell - I actually am getting a static analysis error when trying to bootstrap in the background - [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:..] UI API called from background thread: -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] must be used from main thread only. Is the library calling this API?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks so much for looking into it - but the stack trace I see is coming from the Crashlytics framework's method [CLSCrashReportingController captureInitialNotificationStates]. You can have a look at a demo app I made to repro: https://github.com/michaelcueno/CrashlyticsTest  - You can either set a symbolic breakpoint on [UIApplication statusBarOrientation] or enable the "Main Thread Checker" and pause on issues in Xcode 9. Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: @MikeBonnell - we're seeing exactly the same behaviour, which is what brought me to this thread. `[CLSCrashReportingController captureInitialNotificationStates]` seems to be calling `[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]`.

Comment: Dear @MikeBonnell, This is still an issue `[CLSCrashReportingController captureInitialNotificationStates]` calls `[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]`.

Comment: I don't have any alternatives or workarounds at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the CrashlyticsDelegate protocol (specifically the `crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution` callback) and set yourself as the delegate, then Crashlytics will upload the crash reports asynchronously, so you won’t need to put the initialization to a background thread:

> Just implementing this delegate method will disable all forms of synchronous report submission. This can impact the reliability of reporting crashes very early in application launch.

https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Protocols/CrashlyticsDelegate.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but my latency is from bootstrapping Crashlytics - not from sending a crash report. This method isn't invoked during crashlytics initialization unless a crash happened previously.